# How to calculate the price given the value of the custom input field in cart page woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

On the woocommerce сart page I want to calculate the amount based on the entered coefficient`enter code here`
http://prntscr.com/ny82ge
in cart.php

```
<form action="get">                             
  <input type="number" value="1" class="coef" name="coef">
 </form>
```

in functions.php

```
function add_custom_price( $cart_object ) {
    $coef = $_GET['coef'];
    $price = $product->get_regular_price();
    $nas = $coef * $price/100;
    $final_price = $nas + $price;

    foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {
        $value['data']->set_price($final_price);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the code you write may the right one,

you can use the woocommerce action

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_price', 20, 1)
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: when I insert code add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_price', 20, 1) error 500

Comment: you can check this thread,

[calculate-price](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/272220/woocommerce-before-calculate-totals-in-woocommerce-3-0#answers)